Files are appearing in unstaged changes which I never opened or changed
I see files in unstaged changes which I never opened or changed. There are main branch and my branch and others branch. I do pull changes before I push to the remote. This is the second time it happened to me. What I am doing wrong?
I was expecting only my changes would be reflected in unstaged.

Other than my answer if you need more help, could you be a little clearer and more specific. Walk me through all the steps you took: each branch you were in, the git status at each step, and a list of changes you've made at each step could help a lot.

What files are changed -- is there a pattern? Copying and pasting the output of git status and git diff would help.

git status brings all the files I never worked on with red mark.

If you are certain you didn't make any changes then the issue is probably that uncommited changes from one branch are being carried over to whatever branch you're working with. Before switching branches you should use git stash to stash changes in a branch. If you later want to reapply these changes use git stash apply
